# Return data from promise using function

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, promise, es6-promise

i am created function in javascript to fetch the data from database 
and i return the result but it not give me expected result

**Function**

```
const getData = id => {
  return new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool
      .request()
      .query(`select City,Address,Price from Temp where tempId='${id}'`)
      .then(result => {
        sql.close();
        return result;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        sql.close();
      });
  });
};
```

**Output**

```
Promise {
    _bitField: 0,
    _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
    _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
    _promise0: undefined,
    _receiver0: undefined 
}
```

**Expected Output**

> City, Address, Price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with *promises*, the way to return your result is to resolve it using `then`. You can also handle errors using `catch`. In your case it will look like this

```
// Your function that returns a promise
const getData = id => {
  return new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect().then(pool => {
    return pool
      .request()
      .query(`select City,Address,Price from Temp where tempId='${id}'`)
      .then(result => {
        sql.close();
        return result;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        sql.close();
      });
  });
};

// How you actually get the result
getData('yourIdGoesHere')
    .then(data => {
        // Your data is here
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use async, await to simplify the promise.

```
const getData = async (id) => {
    try {
        const pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(config).connect();
        const result = pool
                        .request()
                        .query(`select City,Address,Price from Temp where tempId='${id}'`)
        sql.close();
        return result;
    } catch (exception) {
        sql.close();
        return;
    }

};
```